# How to test equality of recursive structures?

Tags: haskell

I would like to `typeCheck` two `numberList`s. This causes an infinite loop as it is. What are some solutions to solving my problem?

```
data Type =
    Function Type Type |
    Number |
    Tuple [Type] |
    Limited [Type]
        deriving (Show, Eq)

-- type x is of type y
typeCheck :: Type -> Type -> Bool
typeCheck x y = case y of

    Function ya yr -> case x of
        Function xa xr -> typeCheck xa ya && typeCheck xr yr
        _ -> False


    Number -> x == Number 

    Tuple ys -> case x of 
        Tuple xs | length xs == length ys -> 
            all (==True) $ zipWith typeCheck xs ys
        _ -> False

Limited ys -> case x of
    Limited xs | length ys >= length xs -> 
        all (==True) $ zipWith typeCheck xs ys
    _ -> any (==True) $ map (typeCheck x) ys

{- 
 - A list of numbers can be represented as follows
 - () empty list
 - (1, ()) [1]
 - (1, (2, (3, ()))) [1,2,3]
-}

numberList = Limited [ Tuple [], Tuple [ Number, numberList ] ]
```

Comment: What arguments cause `typeCheck` to not terminate?

Comment: Note: `all (== True)` is `and` and `any (== True)` is `or`.

Comment: @dave4420: `numberList` and `numberList`, according to the first sentence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you recurse through the structures until you reach the last element of both `Tuple`s, which ends up reducing to `typeCheck numberList numberList` again; an obvious infinite recursion. You'll have to restructure your data-type to represent this kind of circularity *explicitly* if you want to be able to check them for equality. For instance, you could add a binding form, like

```
Recursive "numberList" $ Limited [Tuple [], Tuple [Number, Var "numberList"]]
```

or, using [De Bruijn indices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index) (easier to deal with programmatically, more awkward to write for humans):

```
Recursive $ Limited [Tuple [], Tuple [Number, Var 0]]
```

This would necessitate you carry around a stack in `typeChecks`, so that you could detect e.g.

```
typeChecks' [("numberList", ...)] (Var "numberList") (Var "numberList")
```

and resolve it as `True`.

By the way, `all (==True)` ≡ `all id` ≡ `and`; `any (==True)` ≡ `any id` ≡ `or`.

Incidentally, your function can be simplified massively, and avoid most of the additional `length` checks, by using pattern-matching and a manually-recursive `typeChecks` function that ensures the two lists have the same length:

```
typeCheck :: Type -> Type -> Bool
typeCheck (Function as rs) (Function as' rs') =
  typeChecks as as' && typeChecks rs rs'
typeCheck Number Number = True
typeCheck (Tuple xs) (Tuple ys) = typeChecks xs ys
typeCheck x@(Limited xs) (Limited ys)
  | length ys >= length xs = and $ zipWith typeCheck xs ys
  | otherwise = any (typeCheck x) ys
typeCheck _ _ = False

typeChecks :: [Type] -> [Type] -> Bool
typeChecks [] [] = True
typeChecks (x:xs) (y:ys) = typeCheck x y && typeChecks xs ys
typeChecks _ _ = False
```

Comment: The call is to `(==)`, not to `typeCheck` --- it's not a recursive call.

Comment: No, the `Eq` instance is derived, so in that case it just checks for the list of type arguments to be equal.

Comment: I've added an equation for the case you forgot, that's how it differs from `(==)`. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I added my own implementation at the same time :) I'm not sure I understand what it's meant to do though! BTW, that clause was only edited after my answer.